# Trying to Parse a CSV file - adding new data

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I'm trying to parse through a large data set in Excel.

Here is my example data

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that I didn't post that.  Will edit the original post now

Answer (score 0):

Asking for code and not posting any is an off topic reason here but with Record Macro the following might suit, assuming `election` is in ColumnA and starts in Row1:

in B2 (inserted column) and copied down to suit: `=IF(A1="election",B1+1,B1)`
in C1 (inserted column) and copied down to suit: `=IF(A1="V",A1&B1,IF(A1="election",A1,""))`

Select sheet, Copy, Paste Special..., Values, delete ColumA:B.

Comment: Thank you, sorry forgot to start posting some of the macros I was editing.  I will update it so you can take a look.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub ElectionID()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
Set r = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
For I = 1 To r.Rows.Count
    Select Case r(I)
        Case Is = "election"
            J = J + 1
        Case Is = "V"
            r(I) = "V" & J
    End Select
Next I
End Sub
```

If you have a large number of these, and the macro is taking a long time, we can do things like turn off screen updating, and also do the work in VBA arrays instead of on the worksheet.  But I'm keeping this simple initially.